# Select UI module within layout in NUXT

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

```
buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/buefy'
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
]
```

Is there a way to select which module I want to use in which layout? (Or even none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: you cannot choose which module to use where because those will be setup before rending any components, because they will be done at build time. So, you will have globally available components on your app. Hence, since it's global you cannot import them on demand.

But, you will not have any collision tbh, because the components are namespaced out of the box. Example:

```html
<b-button>Buefy button</b-button>

<v-btn>Vuetify button</v-btn>
```

If you want to manually choose the components that you wish to import, it can be done. But it will be really cumbersome and will not add a lot of value IMO since it will need to be done on a per component level.

PS: `nuxt-buefy` is not a `buildModules` install as shown here: https://buefy.org/documentation/start#nuxtjs

---

EDIT for the comments:
I know that for Bulma, you can choose what you import, like this

```css
@import 'bulma/sass/base/generic';
@import 'bulma/sass/elements/_all';
@import 'bulma/sass/form/_all';
@import 'bulma/sass/components/_all';
// @import 'bulma/sass/grid/_all';
// @import 'bulma/sass/layout/_all';
// @import "bulma/sass/helpers/_all" //! this one will add some annoying spacing, DON'T UNCOMMENT :)

@import '~buefy/src/scss/buefy';
```

Looks like you can do the same with Vuetify: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#webpack-install

It will take you some time to try out how to choose (and what to choose) but you should be able to do it.

Comment: Okay, so can I somehow limit which css I want to include? There are possibly conflicts between some base styles.

Comment: Also from buefy doc example, `['nuxt-buefy', { css: false, materialDesignIcons: false }]`, `css: false` is to disable auto-import css?

Comment: As far as I remember, it's to disable the whole CSS and only have the JS functionality of the various components.

Comment: Seems like it from their github: https://github.com/buefy/nuxt-buefy

Comment: Another question, what about adding bootstrap for nuxt as well? Same prefix as for bulma

Comment: Usually, you can change the prefix: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs#individual-components-and-directives Still, having 1 CSS framework is heavy enough. 2 is probably heavily not recommended. 3...hum, lol.

Comment: Well thats why I asked can I somehow programically import em, lets say I have user-profiles and each profile has custom design, and I would like to be able to lend them to use any framewrk of those :D

Comment: At this point, you should create a design-system with various themes, manually crafted thanks to TailwindCSS. As on this page, check "example themes" > https://www.vue-tailwind.com/ This is done by emulating the style of the various frameworks, but this is done in TailwindCSS.